# Array of start and end dates where the proceeding start date = the previous end date +1 WORKDAY

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Is it possible to make two columns of dates (start and end) with only the initial start date and number of days for each task using a single formula?  I can drag formulas down, but I'd rather have the flexibility of an `ARRAYFORMULA`, if at all possible.

I have a list of tasks (that will be ever-changing) with a number of days to complete each task.  I also have a definite start date.  I can get my end dates using `WORKDAY`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B),WORKDAY.INTL(C2:C-1,B2,6,),))
```

, but trying to automatically populate the next start days always results in a circular reference.

```
=ArrayFormula(WORKDAY.INTL(C2:C,B2:B,6,))
```

The next problem is in the [weekend] variable of the `WORKDAY` function.   Since my following start dates don't always fall on the same day, "6" is not always accurate, causing weekends to inadvertently appear as valid workdays.

[Here's my test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LnsJZbh7irfzGmjsv7dT940P9LtzuC9jikS3vmCboqs/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not do it like this:

paste in cell **D2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(
 QUERY(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(DATEVALUE(C2)&":"&DATEVALUE(C2)+SUM(B2:B)*2))), 
 "where not dayofweek(Col1) matches '1|7'"), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(DATEVALUE(C2)&":"&DATEVALUE(C2)+SUM(B2:B)*2))), 
 "where not dayofweek(Col1) matches '1|7'"))))), "^"&JOIN("$|^", 
 IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))*(B2:B)), 
 SIGN(B2:B))))&"$"), "♀", )="♀"))
```

paste in cell **C3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,FILTER(
 QUERY(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(DATEVALUE(C2)&":"&DATEVALUE(C2)+SUM(B2:B)*2))), 
 "where not dayofweek(Col1) matches '1|7'"), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(DATEVALUE(C2)&":"&DATEVALUE(C2)+SUM(B2:B)*2))), 
 "where not dayofweek(Col1) matches '1|7'"))))), "^"&JOIN("$|^", 
 IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))*(B2:B)), 
 SIGN(B2:B))+1))&"$"), "♀", )="♀")))
```

[image: 0]

---

with Holiday list:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(
 QUERY(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(DATEVALUE(C2)&":"&DATEVALUE(C2)+SUM(B2:B)*2))), 
 "where not dayofweek(Col1) matches '1|7' and not Col1 matches '"&
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, H2:H)&"'"), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(DATEVALUE(C2)&":"&DATEVALUE(C2)+SUM(B2:B)*2))), 
 "where not dayofweek(Col1) matches '1|7' and not Col1 matches '"&
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, H2:H)&"'"))))), "^"&JOIN("$|^", 
 IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))*(B2:B)), 
 SIGN(B2:B))))&"$"), "♀", )="♀"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works beautifully!  Is it possible to use a list of holidays similarly to `WORKDAY`?